# Why source device send RTCP packet to remote UDP port 0?

Tags: windows, rtsp, rtcpeerconnection, rtcp, miracast

I'm trying to cast Windows 10 computer screen to an Android TV with miracast protocol and support RTCP extension.

I follow the specification [[MS-WFDPE]: Wi-Fi Display Protocol Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wfdpe/9ac9b0a4-0a94-483d-a8bf-cd7bfea99be0), see [chapter 2.8 RTCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wfdpe/1fb5ba12-8b81-40df-ba4c-5cb3886314ff)

steps:

1. If RTSP M3 request message included "microsoft-rtcp-capability" parameter, TV will reply `microsoft_rtcp_capability: supported\r\n` as below:

```
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Response: RTSP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
        Status: 200
    Date: Sat, 18 Nov 2023 13:19:52 +0000\r\n
    CSeq: 2\r\n
    Content-type: text/parameters
    Content-length: 457
    \r\n
    Line-based text data: text/parameters (8 lines)
        wfd_video_formats: 38 01 01 08 0001ffff 00000000 00000fff 02 0000 0000 13 0780 0438\r\n
        wfd_audio_codecs: LPCM 00000003 02, AAC 00000003 00\r\n
        wfd_client_rtp_ports: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast 1028 0 mode=play\r\n
        wfd_content_protection: none\r\n
        wfd_uibc_capability: input_category_list=HIDC;hidc_cap_list=Keyboard/USB, Mouse/USB, MultiTouch/USB, Gesture/USB, RemoteControl/USB;port=none\r\n
        wfd_display_edid: none\r\n
        wfd_connector_type: 05\r\n
        microsoft_rtcp_capability: supported\r\n
```

2. TV will fill `client_port` field including RTCP port at the SETUP phase as below:

```
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.49.235/wfd1.0/streamid=0 RTSP/1.0\r\n
        Method: SETUP
        URL: rtsp://192.168.49.235/wfd1.0/streamid=0
    Date: Sat, 18 Nov 2023 13:19:53 +0000\r\n
    CSeq: 2\r\n
    Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=1028-1029
    \r\n
```

The source reply:

```
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=1028-1029;server_port=64713-7492;ssrc=866c7a52;rtcp-fb-ssrc=866c7a53
```

After that, the Windows computer sent a RTCP compound packet including a sender report to remote UDP port `0`, but not `1029`. No RTCP packet was received on Android TV and the `1029` port is always not readable.

[image]

The RTCP communication should be established between the local 7492 port and the remote 1029 port. However,  the source device(windows computer) uses the remote 0 port but not 1029, I want to know why.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification said:

[image]

However, the version of Windows 10 on my computer is 1909 version, but not 1507 or 1511. perhaps it also has a bug or is not supported well.

After upgrading to the latest Windows 10 22H2 version, the issue was fixed.